# Get custom attribute in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection, custom-attributes, razor-pages

I have DTO with fields and custom attributes for title of each field.

realization of attribute:

```
  public class TitleAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public TitleAttribute()
    {
    }

    public TitleAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I use this custom attributes for my dto-fields, part of dto-code:

```
    [Title("Stage of sale*")]
    public string StageName { get; set; }

    [Title("Sum in currency Oppty")]
    public decimal Sum { get; set; }

    [Title("Currency")]
    public decimal Currency { get; set; }
```

I need to get titles of all fields and show it in my razor view (like table, for example).
What should i do? Should i create extension method for my dto-class? any ideas? thank you

Comment: Why don't you use Display property instead of a custom property?

Comment: i.e. `[Display(Name = "Stage of sale*")]`. Then, in your view: `@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.StageName)`.

Comment: Or if you can't use out-of-box data annotations for some reason, create your own `HtmlHelper` extensions by copying https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/DisplayNameExtensions.cs !